# Fetch date from String and convert to Date object in Flutter Dart

Tags: date, flutter, dart

I searched a lot, but couldn't find a good solution.
Actually, know the Javascript code to do my problem. But I tried different methods in Dart. 
My issue is I am fetching a time table through an API. And I get the response as

```
05:30 (PTC)
13:10 (PTC)
17:20 (PTC)
```

And I need to get this as

```
5:30 AM
1:10 PM
5:20 PM
```

The code I tried and worked  in Javascript

```
     function tConvert (time) {
  time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];
  if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
    time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
    time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? ' AM' : ' PM'; // Set AM/PM
    time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
  }
  return time.join (''); // return adjusted time or original string
}

//called as
$("#time").html(tConvert(time));
```

One more issue here his 
(PTC) is sometime changed to other codes like (BST) (IST) etc. So just replacing (PTC don't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issues after a long search. So I wished to share my code. 
Thanks to @hiwa Jalal for trying to help.

Steps were taken:

- Removed all strings with RegEx
  `String removeABC = removebrace2.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'), '');`
- Removed spaces and brackets with similar regEx.
- Converted my result into DateFormat

```
 DateTime gotFinalTime = intl.DateFormat('hh:mm').parse(removeABC);
                 String formattedTime = intl.DateFormat.jm().format(gotFinalTime);

                 print(formattedTime);
```

This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to your project

then use `DateFormat.jm().format(yourTime)`

for more information on `DateFormat` class [check here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: But, before that, I need to remove that trailing texts like (BST)/(IST)/(PTC)...So how to achieve it? So I can pass the DateTime object through  ```DateFormat.jm().format(yourTime)``` Currently, time is received as  a ```String```

Comment: Or can replace all the alphabets? I could replace those brackets with
```time.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'),'');
//result: 0530 PTC
```

Comment: Yes, I think creating a regex that only read numbers will work.

Comment: Yupp! Finally, I got the format as  ```eg: 04:45``` Now I tried  ```DateFormat.jm().format(yourTime)``` But it shows  
```Trying to read MMMM from 04:45 at position 0
```